# on wicket's continueToOriginalDestination() method

Tags: wicket

what is the link between backbutton and continueToOriginalDestination(). method.
how to keep url saved for continueToOriginalDestination() method while clcking browsers back button.

Answer (score 9):

`continueToOriginalDestination()` is used when a request was (temporarily) redirected to an intercepting page, for example a login page. When a user requests a secured page but is not yet authenticated, the security framework that hooks into wicket (auth-roles, shiro, swarm/wasp) will present the user with a login page, and store the original URL. When the user has authenticated, you can call `continueToOriginalDestination` and Wicket will process the original request, displaying the requested secured page.

Not only security frameworks can use this, you can do it yourself by throwing a `RestartResponseAtInterceptPage` exception.

The back button has nothing to do with this, nor does it have any affect on the processing of the original destination page. Wicket keeps storing the original destination until a new one is set, or until `continueToOriginalDestination` has been called.

`continueToOriginalDestination` returns `true` when there was a page to go to, and `false` when the user landed on the intercept page directly (e.g. guessing the login page URL or clicking on a link pointing to the login page).

Comment: When Component:continueToOriginalDestination() is called, is there a way to pass parameters to the original destination Wicket redirects to?